# Caching linq-to-sql results?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, caching

Most will recommend caching as a list. I know that is a solution and may be the one I go with. But, what if one wants to be able to treat a cached linq-to-sql with full IQueryable (IEnumerable?) functionality?

If one does try to cache the raw result, an error "Query results cannot be enumerated more then once".

So, to make clear my questions are:

1. Is the hashcode for Lists, IQueryable, and IEnumerable unique?
2. If I want to cache the linq-to-sql result safely AND provide for maximum functionality afterward, how can I do that?

Comment: Caching local data while maintaining full IQueryable capability are conflicts of interest. The purpose of IQueryable in Linq-to-SQL is to translate LINQ expressions into SQL.

Comment: @Kbrimington Perhaps I need an Ienumerable then? I'd like to use the filtering capabilities on the cache result. It would also be ideal that I don't NEED to know whether I'm using cached or non cached data. I admit I've not looked into the interfaces to see which ones are required but I'm fairly sure the list is more limited.. Perhaps the extension methods provide that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have cached an IEnumerable, it is a "hydrated" list that is still queryable itself.  The `AsQueryable()` method can be used to query against the subset of records that are populated into the list:

```
IEnumerable foo = from o in ctx.MyObjects
                  select o;

foo.ToList();

IEnumerable bar = from f in foo.AsQueryable()
                  select f;
```

Here is some more good information on using AsQueryable():
http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/07/31/using-asqueryable-with-linq-to-objects-and-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Here is another good one http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/11/iqueryable-can-kill-your-dog-steal-your-wife-kill-your-will-to-live-etc/

Comment: The `foo.ToList()` you have there won't do anything useful. Is it there for a reason?

Comment: @Mark: The call to ToList() will actually execute the query and populate the list.  Until then it's just an expression tree.

Comment: @Curtis:  The GetHashCode method would work on a List or List<T> the same as any other type.  The default hashing algorithm does some introspection into the state of the object (the fact that it's a list is irrelevant) and combines that with the type of the object to generate a hash that may be used to uniquely identify that *instance* of the list object *for that process.*  An identical instance (by state) in a different process can generate a different hash.

Comment: "The default hashing algorithm does some introspection into the state of the object" No. It only used object identity. It does not look at the contents.

Comment: The AsQuerable method will not magically make your objects queryable again. This will behave just like you did Linq-to-objects (using the Enumerable class). Also, if you cache entities like this you will keep the entire datacontext in memory and also _all other_ entites that you have ever queried with that datacontext. This answer is very dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

> But, what if one wants to be able to treat a cached linq-to-sql with full IQueryable (IEnumerable?) functionality?

The class [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) implements [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx) and you can query it using LINQ if you wish.

> Most will recommend caching as a list.

I'd say it depends on what you plan to do with your cached data. A `List<T>` is fine in many cases. If you want to have fast lookups based on a unique key you might be better off storing the cached data in a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what are you caching?  An IQueryable isn't a result (a query is a question, not an answer).

Further, an IEnumerable isn't a thing, it's merely a description.  There must be some underlying real data structure (like a List or array)